# Read Excel file and skip empty rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-requests, spyder

I have a excel sheet containing data as shown below, It contains data column wise.

```
Rahul     e34   Pradeep  e44  Azhar  t54  
Venkat    r45   Akash    e14  Vipul  r15  Fairo   e45 
Akshay    e44   
Pavan     e24   Asad     t14
```

When i run the below code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\\Users\\Kiran\\Desktop\\Data\\Output1.xlsx')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.to_numpy(),(-1,2)))
df.to_excel("Output2.xlsx")
```

I get output as

```
     0           1
0   Rahul       e34   
1   Pradeep     e44  
2   Azhar       t54  
3       
4   Venkat      r45   
5   Akash       e14  
6   Vipul       r15  
7   Fairo       e45 
8   Akshay      e44    
9       
10      
11      
12  Pavan       e24   
13  Asad        t14
14      
15
```

I need output as shown below

```
Rahul       e34   
Pradeep     e44  
Azhar       t54     
Venkat      r45   
Akash       e14  
Vipul       r15  
Fairo       e45 
Akshay      e44    
Pavan       e24   
Asad        t14
```

Row 1 (0,1) and 1st Column (0,1,2,3,4.....15) should not appear along with how to remove empty spaces. Can anyone please guide me. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `index` & `header` argument in the `df.to_excel()`.
Also use `header=None` while reading excel into pandas DF. If you don't you will be missing an observation in the output file.

Here is the working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.read_excel ('input.xlsx',header=None)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.to_numpy(),(-1,2)))

df.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
clean_df=df[:].astype('str').apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

print(clean_df)

df.to_excel("Output.xlsx",index=False,header=False)
```

Comment: thanks for your code its Working, One issue - i need the data row by row  Right now when i run that code i am getting empty Rows some where in between as explained above.

Comment: Yes I saw that issue mentioned above. However, I didn't face it at all (I used the code provided by you without any alterations) . Check the formatting of excel file from which you are creating the DF. If the issue persists I would suggest you to convert the input file to csv and try the same.

Comment: Converted  input file to csv but still it gives empty rows in between, trying hard to fix the issue but i am unable to succeed, can you help

Comment: Upload the excel file you are using as well as code to somewhere (ex: gdrive) and give me the link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1v3SvaWwsNsvRVzmcUHrQeUNGLQ1hlGj3?usp=sharing The link contains 2 consolidated excel sheet (Input.xlsx Input sheet and Output.xlsx Output sheet) The code remains the same as written above.

Comment: @Kiran check your email I have asked for access.

Comment: I have given the access, Kindly check and let me know your comments

Comment: your formatting of the excel was off. You needed to clean your data-frame. I have edited the answer with the latest code you can use it. It will give you desired output.

Comment: When i run the updated code I get error as "    raise TypeError("data type '{}' not understood".format(dtype))

TypeError: data type 'string' not understood"

Comment: renamed "String" to "str" its working thanks for you code.