# How can I skip blank lines in Excel using Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a set of excel data that contains blocks, each block represents a number, and the blocks are separated by a space. How can I skip that space when I convert each block to an image, knowing that I will use a boucle to convert all blocks into a set of images

Comment: This might answer your question. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432440/read-excel-file-and-skip-empty-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432440/read-excel-file-and-skip-empty-rows)

Comment: I don't want to clear it, I want to skip it when I use loop

Comment: Hi @Linda, can you include a sample of your data and your expected output?